# iOS 5.0 Modal View Not Rotating(Story Boards)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, storyboard

I use story boards. In every view controler I want to rotate I included this method like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

in iOS 6 it rotates just fine to the proper views I have for landscape and portrait in my story boards.

in iOS 5 the parent view contoller rotates but the modals don't rotate while they are on the screen, they only rotate before they are on the screen but never during. So when a user changes orientation it remains the same. A parent will change while on screen but the modal will take on the orientation the parent had but will not change while on screen. How do I get my modal views to work like iOS 6 where they will rotate when on the screen. The modal view were created via the storyboard.

Edit*

When I do a popover to a modal, the modal doesn't rotate. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Rotation is handled differently in iOS5 and iOS6. I use the below code to support both versions.

```
// iOS5
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

// iOS6
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` is deprecated in iOS6. You can read here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:

Comment: That's funny because it works fine on iOS6, I'll deal with that deprecation later. However I do use

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

for iOS 5 but the problem is, it's not rotating on modal views.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read the question properly haha. Is this code instead both the modal viewController and the viewController presenting the modal?

Comment: A user starts the app in iOS 5 iPad. On the very first screen when they rotate it automatically rotates.

When they click on a button, the next view is presented modally and it will appear in whatever orientation the first view was in. 

When a user changes orientation, while the model view is up the screen will not change orientation until the modal view is closed.

Comment: Does the view behind the modal rotate?

Comment: Yes it does. The parent view controller does.When you go back it will be in the new orientation

Comment: Hmm very odd. Are you using storyboards or interface builder? And if so are the appropriate boxes check in them?

Comment: Storyboards, I also have auto-layouts unchecked because it crashes on iOS 5 with it checked.